# Android Eclipse - Table Row Button - Formatting Issue

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a Table Layout with multiple Table Rows, but one problem.

I would like the two buttons labeled "0" to combine into one large button and still look flush with the formatting style.

Here is a screen:

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.funkycalc.MainActivtiy\" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="66dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CLR" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DEL" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button15"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button16"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="/" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="." />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="x" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button21"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
    android:text="=" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add: `android:layout_span="2"` to your:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button17"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="0" />
```

so you get:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button17"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="0" 
android:layout_span"2" /> //number of columns button spans over
```

**edit:** Don't forget to delete your button19

Answer (score 0):

You should use span in the last row in the following way:

```
    <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0"
                android:layout_span="2"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button18"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="." />

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button20"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="x" />
    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Man you got to try this
[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.funkycalc.MainActivtiy\">

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="66dp">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CLR" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DEL" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button15"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button16"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="/" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button17"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button18"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="." />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button20"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="x" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button21"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
    android:text="=" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.funkycalc.MainActivtiy\" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="66dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CLR" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DEL" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button15"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button16"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="/" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="." />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="x" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button21"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
    android:text="=" />
```